# How can we check whether we have a valid connection?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm using winsock for implementing my simple client application and came up with a question about checking for active connection. Let me provide the piece of code:

```
class Connection
{
private:
    SOCKET socket_;
public:
    void connect(const char* host, const int& port);
    //other member functions
}

void Connection::connect(const char* host, const int& port)
{
        socket_ = INVALID_SOCKET;
        WSAData wsaData;
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        addrinfo hints = addrinfo(), *result;
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        if(getaddrinfo(host, std::to_string(port).c_str() != 0, &hints, &result)
        {
                throw std::exception("Address initialization failed\n");
        }
        for(ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
        {
                socket_ = socket(ptr->ai_family, 
                                 ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);  //1
                if(socket_ = INVALID_SOCKET){
                      continue;
                }
                connect(socket_, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen); //2
                break;
        }
}
```

I need to check if we have an active connection. The thing is the fact that `socket_ != INVALID_SOCKET` doesn't imply that we don't have the active connection (For instance, between `//1` after obtaining the valid socket value and `//2` before invocation of `connect` function). How we could check whether we have a valid connection?

Comment: `before invocation of connect function ... How we could check whether we have a valid connection?` How is it possible to have a connection before calling `connect()`?

Comment: @AtlasC1 You didn't understand. I meant it is possible that socket holds a valid value, but is not connected.

Comment: Classic bug: `if (socket_ = INVALID_SOCKET)`

Comment: What is a *valid value* for a socket? What has *valid value* to do with a socket being *connected"? A socket can exist in *unconnected* state but that socket is a *valid* socket descriptor still. An unconnected socket however will return `WSAENOTCONN` e.g. when calling `getpeername()`

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can reliably detect a broken connection in TCP is by trying to write to it. If the connection has broken, eventually this will cause `send()` to return -1 with `errno == ECONNRESET.` It won't happen on the first such write, and it may take several more writes (or reads after the first such write) because of buffering.

You can detect a *possibly* broken connection by using read timeouts. However the selection of timeout value depends on many factors, and a read timeout may mean nothing more than the timeout being too short for the request in the current state of the system.